# How to send the actuat post data in WP Webhook plugins in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, automation, zapier, learndash

I am creating job listing using WP Job Manager plugin. I am detecting that trigger using WP Webhooks and then sending that data to Zapier. But everytime, I get only the default outgoing data. I don't have stuff like company name, website, location etc. [image: default data][image: Data I want]

I tried adding {:company_name:} to my webhook url and retreive that using data mapping. But no luck.

Comment: looks like the configuration should comes from WP Webhooks  plugin, the JSON you have posed is WP API

Comment: Thanks Nafi. Really appreciate your time. 
That's also what I thought but I don't have any idea how to set that up. WP Webhooks plugin don't have any setting where I can add/remove my desired data. Or at least I couldn't find it.

I also thought of editing the code but as I'm new to this, I have no idea where to start. Any help regarding that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In order to understand your requirement further please post here what kind of data you receive on Zapier end